# Alternative of "??" for non nullable types (e.g. when looking up dictionary keys)

Tags: c#, syntactic-sugar

It's very convenient using inline sugar like that: `obj?.func();` and `obj ?? anotherObj`

But I'm trying to find an alternative to the same approach in case I want to pull data from a dictionary without knowing whether the dictionary has the key I'm looking for or not.

Specifically I'd like to do something equivalent to:

`someDictionary[someKey] ?? anotherValue` such that, if key exists it would use the corresponding value in the dictionary and if not, it will use `anotherValue`. Obviously it's not possible to use as I wrote it here since it makes no sense, but the idea behind it is sound.

Is there a way to simplify it to be used inline, without making a separate check with `if`?

Comment: It would help if you could give a concrete example including the actual types involved - because that makes it easier to give a concrete example in the answer too.

Comment: `T obj = dict.TryGetKey(key, out T value) ? value : defaultValue`

Comment: @JonSkeet in my actual case I simply use <enum,double> as dictionary format.

Comment: @NewProger: Right, so please include a concrete example *in the question* (not with `enum`, but with a real type). It's so much easier to understand a question when there's a very specific example.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă I think you meant `TryGetValue`

Comment: @juharr Yes, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace if checking with ternary operator

```cs
 var value = someDictionary.TryGetValue(someKey, out var val) ? val : anotherValue;
```

Comment: This answer works, but with .NET Core 2+ and C# 7+, this has been implemented in CollectionExtensions. Basically @NewProger only needs to use `var value = someDictonary.GetValueOrDefault(someKey, anotherValue);`

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti Thanks! I will remember it